# c++ help passing a vector index to a function

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I know how to pass a vector to a function, but how do I pass a vector index to a function, or at least specify which index the function is modifying. For example, I'm working on a Car class and it has a vector if wheel pointers and in order to remove one of the wheels my function looks like this:

```
Wheel& remove() {
    for (int i = 0; i < wheels.size(); i++) {
        if (wheels[i].position == wheels.at(i)) {
            ??
        }
```

what do I need to pass to the function in order to specify which wheel I want removed?  When a wheel is removed, the position where it was is still there and can be filled by another wheel. Let's say for example the car had 4 wheels...if I wanted to remove the 2nd index in the wheel vector, what does the function argument for remove() need to take in order to do it?  Should I pass in the vector and then the specific index....and if so, what does the syntax look like?

Comment: Are you sure you are not over-complicating things? Does you Car class really need to handle arbitrary numbers of wheels?

Comment: @Andrey: How many wheels does a regular sedan has and a big truck? 4 vs 6 usually ;)

Comment: Well, my professor is the one who complicated things.  In the instructions he said: Not all cars are built to hold four wheels, some are built to have only three (tricycles?) while others have more. But whatever they are built for that is all they can hold.
          o The engine and the wheels are kept in the car as pointers to allow the parts to be removed or swapped with other parts.

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass an integer to specify which one you would like to remove

```
void RemoveWheel(int i)
{
    if( (i<wheels.size()) and (i>=0) )
        wheels.erase(wheels.begin()+i);
}
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/erase/

If you want to leave the space for another wheel than you should define `wheels` as a vector of pointers and just delete object at the i-th position and save NULL instead of it.

```
vector<Wheel *> wheels;

void RemoveWheel(int i)
{
    if( (i<wheels.size()) and (i>=0) ) {
        delete wheels[i];
        wheels[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: That pointer suggestion is wrong. The vector will never reallocate on erase so the memory will be there either way. And adding custom memory management on top of vector is just absurd (after all, vector does memory management for you!)

Comment: @ltjax: I'm not agree with you. Read http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/erase/ `Because vectors keep an array format, erasing on positions other than the vector end also moves all the elements after the segment erased to their new positions`. Using `vector<Wheels *>` makes sense here because we can suppose that the `Car` has some constant number of `Wheels`, you can not add a 5th wheel to the sedan.

Comment: What exactly is your point here? I know vector moves the elements around - I might have misunderstood what you meant with space, but doing that stuff with bare pointers isn't great either way. if you want "optional" wheels in some positions, you should use something that more clearly reflects that, like `boost::optional`

Comment: I was just trying to answer the question the way it was asked. And I'm not talking about "optional" wheels. Imagine you want to replace one wheel - you should remove it first and replace with a new instance.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not entirely clear to me, but to remove an element from a vector, given an index i, you can do this:

```
wheels.erase(wheels.begin() + i);
```

But this would be better:

```
auto e = std::remove_if(wheels.begin(), wheels.end(),
             [](const Wheel & wheel) {
                 return wheel.position == wheel;
             });
wheels.erase(e,wheels.end());
```

Although I'm not sure if you want to remove every element that fits that criteria, or just the first.  If you would show the logic in pseudocode of what you want to do, that would help.